# latex to html conversion with make4ht - pictures' width and height

Tags: diagrams, tex4ht, size, make4ht

I'm approaching the issue of converting TeX documents to html.
After some googling and reading, I ended up with make4ht.
As a starting point, I'm trying to convert a simple tex document to html (+css) with make4ht.
It worked, but I want to modify its behavior wrt pictures:
in the TeX file I have:

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./image.png}
```

and in the html file I find:

```
<img width='345' height='345' alt='PIC' src='./image.png' />
```

Where these sizes come from? What I would like to be able to obtain is:

```
<img alt='PIC' src='./image.png' />
```

in the html file (no width and height) and the following lines:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```

in the css file.

This way, I have the images that adapt automatically to browser width and maintain their aspect ratio.

Is there an easy way to have this?
Ideally I would like this to be included in the mk4 file (where I already set up the mathjax, mathml commands) or in the config file.
Otherwise, may you direct me to a make4ht for dummies?

Many thanks for any input

```
 Mario
```

Answer (score 4):

You can find some information about image sizes in the [work in progress TeX4ht documentation](https://www.kodymirus.cz/tex4ht-doc/Howto.html#x4-220003.3.2). By default, it uses dimensions provided by Graphicx package, so the value `345` is related to your `\textwidth`. Unfortunately, Graphicx in the DVI mode cannot read image dimensions directly, so you get wrong height, it just uses the same dimension as for width. You can create a special file that contains dimensions for each graphics file using the

```
ebb -x *.png
```

command. You will get the correct height then.

If you don't want to use image dimensions at all, you can use `\Configure{Gin-dim}`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{Gin-dim}{}
\Css{img {
    max-width: 100\%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\string\9; 
}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The empty argument will just disable dimension attributes in the HTML file.

This is the resulting HTML:

```
<p class='noindent'><img alt='PIC' src='example-image.png' /> </p>
```

and CSS:

```
img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; width: auto\9; }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It worked!!!